# Prove that $f$ doesn't depend on the variable $x_i$

Tags: real-analysis

everybody!

Problem:
"A set $X \subset R^n$ is said to be i-convex when, for every $a,b \in X$, such that $b=a+te_i$, we have $[a,b] \subset X$. Prove that if the open set $U \subset R^n$ is i-convex and the function $f: U \rightarrow R$ has $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)=0$, for all $x \in U$, then $f$ doesn't depend on the variable $x_i$, i.e., $x,x+te_i \in U \Rightarrow f(x+te_i)=f(x)$".

My doubt is the following: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)= lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+te_i)-f(x)}{t} \Rightarrow lim_{t \rightarrow 0} f(x+te_i)-f(x)= lim_{t \rightarrow o}t. \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}=0$. It doesn't follow that $f(x+te_i)-f(x)=o$, for all $x, x+te_i \in U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(s):=f(x+s e_i)$. Then $g$ is differentiable in (a neighbourhood of) $[0,t]$ and $g'(s)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(s+h)-g(s)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+se_i+he_i)-f(x+se_i)}{h}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x+se_i)=0$, since $x+se_i\in U$ for each $s\in[0,t]$ (since $U$ is $i$-convex). Thus, $g$ is constant; in paticular, $g(0)=g(t)$, which is equivalent to $f(x)=f(x+te_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in U$, let $g(t) = f(x + te_i)$. Then
\begin{equation*}
  g'(t) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(t+h) - g(t)}{h}
     = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f((x+te_i)+he_i)-f(x+te_i)}{h}
     = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x+te_i) = 0.
\end{equation*}
Thus $g(t) = f(x+te_i)$ is constant for any $x$, so that $f$ does not depend on $x_i$.